# Replacing values between rasters

Tags: r, raster

I'm simplifying my question a bit, so hopefully, it makes sense.

I have three rasters that I'm working with.

```
library(raster)
LC <- raster("finalRRaster2018.tif")
nativeAET <- raster('kohala_aet_mm_ann_int.tif')
nonnativeAET <- raster('pred_AET.tif`)
```

The raster `LC` is a raster with landcover attribute values 1 being native landcover and 0 being non-native landcover.

The `nativeAET` and nonnativeAET are rasters of evapotranspiration under native species and `nonnative` species respectively.  Both rasters have attributes between [0,15000]

What id like to do is replace all the values of 1 with the `nativeAET` values and all the values of 0 with the `nonnativeAET` values.

My idea is to transform the landcover raster (with values 1 or 0) to an AET raster (with values between 0 and 15000).

I used the following code

```
native <- values(LC) == 1
nonative <- values(LC) ==0
LC[native] <- values(nativeAET)[native]
LC[nonnative] <- values(nonnativeAET)[nonnative]
```

but when I plot my graphs, i get the warning `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

and the plot looks something like this,

[image]

My problem is I would expect the resulting plot to not look as chunky.  I feel like the rasters are not aligning properly but when i check the extent and dimensions of the rasters, they all seem to share the same projections.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The question would be easier to answer if you provided some code-generated example data.

Example data:

```
library(raster)
nativeAET <- nonnativeAET <- LC <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=4)
values(nativeAET) <- 1:16
values(nonnativeAET) <- 21:36
values(LC) <- c(rep(0,8), rep(1,8))
```

Approach 1:

```
AETnative <- mask(nativeAET, LC, maskvalue=1, updatevalue=0)
AETnonnative <- mask(nonnativeAET, LC, maskvalue=0, updatevalue=0)
AET <- AETnative + AETnonnative
```

Approach 2:

```
AET <- mask(nativeAET, LC, maskvalue=1)
AET <- cover(AET, nonnativeAET)
```

Comment: Approach 1 worked perfectly!  Genius response.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work (and is fast) assuming that the typo in `nonative` (one `"n"`) is corrected.

The error probably comes from the difference in the spatial resolution of your rasters. Consequently, `ncell(LC) != ncell(nativeAET)` and `ncell(LC) != ncell(nonnativeAET)`. If it is not the case, you need to resample your raster using for instance:

```
nativeAET <- resample(LC, nativeAET, method='ngb')
nonnativeAET <- resample(LC, nonnativeAET, method='ngb')
```

If you only have two values in the LC raster (0 and 1), you can speed up your code by doing:

```
AET <- nativeAET 
AET[values(LC) == 0] <- values(nonnativeAET)[values(LC) == 0]
```

Comment: Your approach would work for small datasets but would be problematic for large rasters. It is better to avoid loading all values into memory by using `values( )` and/or `[ ]`

Comment: @RobertHijmans Good point, thank you for letting me know. I guess it depends on the application, your config and the rasters size. Anyway, I +1 your answer as I did not know the `cover` function which looks very interesting. I take the opportunity to thank you for this awesome package :)